# Axis titles on vioplot

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I want to make a violin plot which is working fine. I have created the plot and added a title using the functions:

```
library(vioplot)
vioplot(x1, x2, x3, names=c("red", "green", "blue"), col="aliceblue") col="aliceblue")
title("Violin Plot")
```

But can't get the y or x axis titles which are the last things I need. I have tried.

> ylab=("response")
>
> ylab("response")
>
> ylabel=("response")
>
> ylabel("response")

All separately but it is not working. Do I have to include  the y axis title in the main code for the plot?

Likewise I cannot label the X-axis ("colours").

Is this something which is beyond vioplot? and is there a way round it that is relatively basic?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If`vioplot` (from an unnamed package) is a base or lattice graphics function, then you should set `ylab=""` in the call, and you can then use `title(ylab="response", xlab="colours")` to fill in with "response"/"colours" or whatever character values you desire. The `title` function is used (after a `plot`-like call) for several named locations on the abstract base plot layout: "main" for what most people would call "title", and/or "xlab" and "ylab" for the centered axis-descriptions (but not the tick labels) .

```
?title
```

Comment: `vioplot` is the also the package containing the function.  I've edited the OP.

Comment: I tried DWin solution here with vioplot and it's working fine on dummy data. Didn't know about the vioplot package.